# Get property value of object/array based on a string containing directory path

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

Is there a way to do something like parse? but instead of parsing a stringified object, i'm supposed get the value based on an object path

```
let myObject = {
    property1: {
        property2: [
            {
                property3: "Hello World"
            }
        ]
    }
};

let path = "myObject.property1.property2[0].property3";
let value = JSON.parse(path);
```

expected value: "Hello World"

Comment: You're looking for `eval(path)`. However, don't use eval().

Comment: eval works, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to use it.